# Avoiding merge conflicts in git workflow

Tags: git, github, rebase

I would like some help with my git workflow on a project I am working on with another developer. It seems to be generating a large number of merge conflicts, and I want to make sure I am not making a dumb mistake.

First, our "main" branch is called `develop`. It is considered the canon branch of source code, it is god. `develop` is merged into `master` whenever we have a release version, and the commit is tagged with a SemVer version. From my understanding this is fairly standard.

Whenever a feature / bit of code needs to be worked on, a branch is broken off the HEAD of `develop` called `developer/feature-name`. Very often these branches will overlap in scope, as we work on similar things at the same time. These branches are considered private, meaning we do not commit to each others branches with out permission from the other.

If we want to make our changes public, we rebase against develop, and then merge into develop a la:

```
            --->E--->F developer/feature-branch
           /
A--->B--->C--->D       develop


AFTER git rebase develop + git checkout develop && git merge developer/feature-branch

A--->B--->C--->D--->E--->F develop developer/feature-branch
```

The feature branch is left open until the feature is complete, afterwards its rebased + merged like above, then deleted.

The other developer will then rebase his branch against develop. and at that point, everyone is up to date. This is where I seem to be getting a large number of merge conflicts, even in consequential ones, where I did not add a line, but he did, etc.

Due to the merge conflicts, I thought it best to come on here and see if I was doing things correctly, as I have not seen anything online that is similar to the workflow I described.

Any opinion is welcome, and thanks for the help.

EDIT #1:

An example of the merge conflicts I get:

```
>>>>>> somecommitid
======
// Look, I added a comment!
<<<<<< Added this really cool comment, fixes Issue #7
```

Comment: If there's overlap, your features aren't fine-grained enough to split. Share a branch and fix conflicts as they occur.

Comment: @CodeGnome, when you say share a branch, share one feature branch like `common/the-feature`? The main reason for having independent branches is so we can rebase freely without the worry of damaging  the history.

Comment: Is I understand,  you have merge conflicts in files where you don't make any changes, but other programmers does?

Comment: @gomons, sometimes, yes. But normally its conflicts like adding one line, a comment, etc, In a file we both edited.
Something in my mind git should be able to handle (this may be where I am flawed). EDIT: Edited question to proivde example.

Comment: Have you looked a this: https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html ? Not sure if it is reliable though...

Comment: @Wikiii122 Thanks, it looks interesting, although my suspicion is that the conflicts are a result of how the rebase / merge process is taking place, but nevertheless it looks like a good read, thanks for the help!

Comment: it always helps to set merge.conflictStyle = diff3 to see the base version.

Comment: do you cherrypick commits from each other?

Comment: @max630 No, we don't. We strictly follow the diagram above to avoid contaminated history. Thanks for the conflictStyle idea, it may help!